# (16.04) Budgie Desktop Environment

Tags: 16.04, budgie

My question is whether installing the budgie DE would install its own compatible applications with it, causing a clash in applications with my already installed Unity? By that I mean file managers or stuff like that.

Basically, will it install more applications with it or just the budgie shell?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For 16.04 budgie-desktop is available through the `ppa:budgie-remix/ppa`

By installing the whole desktop environment (via the package `budgie-desktop-environment`) you install all the associated applications and configuration that team of developers have recommended.

By itself, these applications would normally complement any other desktop-environment you have installed including Unity.

Since you have mentioned Unity - Unity and the 16.04 repositories contain an old version of Nautilus - v3.14.  This has all the patching to make that version of Nautilus work well with Unity.

In that particular PPA - Nautilus is v3.18 - this does not have the Unity patch-work.  Whilst you can pin Nautilus v3.14 so that it does not get upgraded, you should note 3.14 is not compatible with budgie-desktop - it freezes the desktop if you choose some of the client-side-decoration buttons.